# Why did Summer get married?

Tags: plot-explanation, 500-days-of-summer

In all the movie 500 days of Summer, we saw Summer didn't believe in true love and didn't want to have a boyfriend. But in the end, she got married with the man she and Tom met in the bar.

What made Summer decide to get married while not believing in love? We can see Tom was too naive and dreamy. It meant Summer couldn't love Tom but how about the man in the bar? Why did she choose him?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because she felt sure about the man she married (not explaining in detail), something she wasn't with Tom:

> Summer: I just... I just woke up one day and I knew.
>
> Tom: Knew what?
>
> Summer: What I was never sure of with you.

She says that Tom was right about true love existing, it's just not been true love between her and Tom.

Comment: sometimes one just knows it, hard to put in other words